# Is there any way to pass a variable to IDENT_CURRENT?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

The title basically says it all.  I want to write a stored procedure into which I pass a table name and out of which I get the IDENT_CURRENT value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetCurrentIdentityOfTable(@TableName sysname) AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT (@TableName) AS CurrentIdentity;
END;
GO

-- Usage
EXEC usp_GetCurrentIdentityOfTable 'tablename'
```

Comment: Well, isn't that embarrassing.  That is the obvious answer which I had tried and got an SQL error message.  I fiddled with it for a while then gave up and decided to ask for help here.  I still don't know what I was doing wrong originally.  Marked as answer.